# Run youtube-dl periodically

Tags: batch-file, youtube-dl

Say I have some problems with my connection to youtube, and keep getting WinError 10060 when downloading a full channel from time to time - and most importantly got desperate from trying to fix that (The problem is not with a specific video, as when I start over it downloads normally).

My aim is to bypass this by creating a batch file with an infinite loop which will run youtube-dl again with the same parameters after this error occurs.

I've been searching for a solution and my current loop bat contains this:

```
:LOOP
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
call MainDownload.bat
echo "Stop Recorded">> log.txt
if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :LOOP
```

After trying this I can see a "stop recorded" on my log when it happens, but the MainDownload.bat won't run again.

Can anyone offer a solution which will cause this to run infinitely until I manually close it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just get rid of `if not ErrorLevel 1` and have it state `goto :LOOP`

Comment: In that case, is there anyway to flag an error with a specific video or any other error? Like bubbling it up to the log text?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. You have not posted an MCVE. What values does MainDownload.bat return under what conditions?

Comment: MainDownload.bat contains a simple youtube-dl execution: `youtube-dl -v -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" --yes-playlist --download-archive DownloadedVideosArchive -o "%%(uploader)s/%%(playlist)s/%%(playlist_index)s - %%(title)s [%%(upload_date)s].%%(ext)s" --batch-file Playlists.txt`, I didn't find any way to distinct between errors in the youtube-dl readme, but I think the solution above will suffice for now, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `youtube-dl.exe` without parameters you'll get an error.
if you check the `errorlevel` after this you will get 2. So `youtube-dl` set an errorlevel when an error occur !

```
@echo off
youtube-dl.exe 2>nul
echo %errorlevel%
```

Run `youtube-dl`directly in the bat to get the good `errorlevel`.

Something like this :

```
@echo off

:LOOP
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
youtube-dl -v -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" --yes-playlist --download-archive DownloadedVideosArchive -o "%%(uploader)s/%%(playlist)s/%%(playlist_index)s - %%(title)s [%%(upload_date)s].%%(ext)s" --batch-file Playlists.txt
if %errorlevel% GTR 0 (
    echo [%time%] "Stop Recorded" >> log.txt
    goto :LOOP
)
```